# OnCheckedChanged not working in Fragment Android

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-xml, android-checkbox

Hi in fragment an getting the value of checkbox using **OnCheckedChanged** but its not working, like not ven calling the method when I check the CheckBox. Below is the code how its imlemented.

The XML file of how CheckBox is used.

```
     <CheckBox
      android:id="@+id/cbDefault"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight=".2" />
```

The Java code for fragment is below

```
import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class ProfileFrag extends AbsFragment implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

private EditText defaultIdText;
private EditText customText;
private EditText randomText;
private TextView phoneText;
private Button setButton;
protected ProfileUpdate profUpdate;
protected String sDefaultId;
protected String sCustomId;
protected String sRandomId;
protected String sPhoneId;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View profView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intermediate_screen,
            container, false);

    defaultIdText = (EditText) profView.findViewById(R.id.etDefault);
    customText = (EditText) profView.findViewById(R.id.etCustom);
    randomText = (EditText) profView.findViewById(R.id.etUname);
    phoneText = (EditText) profView.findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNumber);

    return profView;
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    mSharedData = new SharedData(getActivity());
    //
    // phoneNumber = DeviceIdGen.DevicePhoneNum(getActivity());

    phoneText.setText(mSharedData.getPhNum());
    randomText.setText(mSharedData.getRandomId());
    customText.setText(mSharedData.getCustomId());
    defaultIdText.setText(mSharedData.getDefaultId());


@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (buttonView.getId()) {

    case R.id.cbDefault:
        sDefaultId = defaultIdText.getText().toString();
        mSharedData.setUniqueid(sDefaultId);
        mSharedData.commit();

        break;

    case R.id.cbCustom:
        sCustomId = customText.getText().toString();
        mSharedData.setUniqueid(sCustomId);
        mSharedData.commit();
        break;

    case R.id.cbRandom:

        mSharedData.setUniqueid(sRandomId);
        mSharedData.commit();
        default:
        break;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: `set setOnCheckedChangeListener as a inner class`

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232087/fragment-causing-npe-upon-starting-service-with-oncheckedchanged](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22232087/fragment-causing-npe-upon-starting-service-with-oncheckedchanged)

Comment: @MD I have four checkbox. So was checking to go for switch case or an optimized way instead of using like given in the above link

Comment: My issue was that Android Databinding overrode my check change listener. So I removed the `android:checked="@={}` binding. Probably not applicable in 2015.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not map your checkbox in your code..try doing this..

```
Checkbox mCb=(Checkbox)profView.findViewById(R.id.cbDefault);
mCb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

must implement the interface **OnCheckedChangeListener**

Comment: Am getting the below error. **The method setOnCheckedChangeListener(CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener) in the type CompoundButton is not applicable for the arguments (Activity)**

Answer (score 2):

Modify your `onCreateView`method to below and check the documented code

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View profView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.intermediate_screen,
            container, false);
    // Initialize your checkbox
    Checkbox mChkbx=(Checkbox)profView.findViewById(R.id.cbDefault);

    // Assign listener to the checkbox
    mChkbx.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    defaultIdText = (EditText) profView.findViewById(R.id.etDefault);
    customText = (EditText) profView.findViewById(R.id.etCustom);
    randomText = (EditText) profView.findViewById(R.id.etUname);
    phoneText = (EditText) profView.findViewById(R.id.etPhoneNumber);

    return profView;
}
```

Comment: I think that `setOnCheckedChangeListener` should not be called with `getActivity` but with `ProfileFrag.this` because it's this class that implements `OnCheckedChangeListener` (and not the parent activity)

Answer (score 0):

> for fragment first we need to implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener see this example

```
public class TabAdvertiser extends Fragment implements android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener {

CheckBox mCbShowPwd;
EditText userName,password;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getActivity());
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, container, false);
    userName=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    password=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.input_password);
    // get the show/hide password Checkbox
    mCbShowPwd = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.cbShowPwd);
    mCbShowPwd.setOnCheckedChangeListener(TabAdvertiser.this);
    return view;
}
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
    // checkbox status is changed from uncheck to checked.
    if (!isChecked) {
        // show password
        password.setTransformationMethod(PasswordTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    } else {
        // hide password
        password.setTransformationMethod(HideReturnsTransformationMethod.getInstance());
    }
}
```

}